# Azure Function App throws exceptions when debug is starting locally

Tags: c#, .net, windows, azure-functions

I am debugging a function app on a windows 10 machine. The app is running on net6. And when starting the debug process it throws these 2 exceptions, but still compiles.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

These 2 are thrown when starting the debug session locally. Everything still works fine though and the app runs locally as well as published to azure.

Do I have to worry about these errors? Any idea what could be the cause of it?

full debug output:

```
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\func.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Runtime.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Autofac.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Collections.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.IO.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\netstandard.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Security.AccessControl.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Linq.Expressions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Linq.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Private.Uri.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.ObjectModel.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Data.Common.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Private.Xml.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.ComponentModel.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Threading.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Reflection.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Globalization.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Colors.Net.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Console.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Xml.XDocument.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Net.Http.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Memory.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Threading.Thread.dll'. 
The thread 0x9ac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\YamlDotNet.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\DurableTask.AzureStorage.Internal.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\DurableTask.Core.Internal.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\AccentedCommandLineParser.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Azure.Identity.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Azure.Core.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Net.Security.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Net.Sockets.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\NuGet.Versioning.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Net.NameResolution.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Security.Claims.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Build.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.NET.StringTools.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Text.Json.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'. 
[...<removed some lines because of stackoverflow character limit>...]
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Http.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Grpc.Core.Api.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Yarp.ReverseProxy.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Azure.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Azure.Storage.Blobs.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.IO.Pipelines.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Reactive.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.IO.Compression.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Grpc.Net.Common.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Google.Protobuf.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.AppContext.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.IO.FileSystem.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.IO.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\Test\StandupFunctionApp\StandupFunctionApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\bin\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tables.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\Test\StandupFunctionApp\StandupFunctionApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\bin\Microsoft.Extensions.Azure.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\Test\StandupFunctionApp\StandupFunctionApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\bin\Azure.Data.Tables.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\Test\StandupFunctionApp\StandupFunctionApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\bin\Azure.Core.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Rpc.Core.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Azure.Storage.Common.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Memory.Data.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll'. 
The thread 0x2724 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\NuGet.ProjectModel.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\NuGet.Common.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\NuGet.LibraryModel.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\Test\StandupFunctionApp\StandupFunctionApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\bin\StandupFunctionApp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Reflection.Emit.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'ScriptHost'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\Test\StandupFunctionApp\StandupFunctionApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\bin\Azure.Identity.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\Test\StandupFunctionApp\StandupFunctionApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\bin\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Web.HttpUtility.dll'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.60.0\cli_x64\System.Collections.Specialized.dll'.
```

Comment: Can you share the code what you have tried and share the host.json and function.json properties in your application?

Comment: which trigger your using  like http or timer?

Answer (score 0):

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

- This exception is thrown when a method is invoked and if any one of the passed arguments is null which should never be null.

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

This exception is thrown while attempting to access a file that does not exist/missing on disk fails.

**Few other causes:**

- If you are using incorrect or missing file path in `appsettings.json` file.
- Version Incompatibility.
- Upgrade the Function version to v4.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

---

***I have checked my Http function logs, those exceptions don't have much impact in function execution.***

**My Function Logs:**

```
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\func.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.NET.StringTools.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\System.Text.Json.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
<Removed few logs>
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\System.Memory.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x2378 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\System.IO.FileSystem.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\System.IO.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\Source\Repos\FunctionApp2\FunctionApp2\bin\Debug\net6.0\bin\FunctionApp2.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\System.Reflection.Emit.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'ScriptHost'. 
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\System.Web.HttpUtility.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\System.Collections.Specialized.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x1658 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Common.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\usern\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.64.0\cli_x64\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[15956] func.exe' has exited with code 3221225786 (0xc000013a).
```